# Open XML run-time instead of SDK

Tags: excel, openxml, openxml-sdk, officedev

*This question is related to understand a better way of releasing my application.*

I have an application that process Excel Spreadsheets with [Open XML SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425).I'm thinking of mentioning it as a prerequisite of my application so that users can download it beforehand.

My question is, whether there is a Open XML run-time only installer that a non technical user cold use. Because the "Open XML SDK" is convincing that it is a developer tool.

Appreciate your thoughts and suggestion in advance on this.

Answer (score 0):

Using the OpenXML SDK from a .NET application is simply adding a reference to the DLL. The build process then copies that DLL to the bin where it can be packaged and distributed with your application. In short, there is no need for the end user of the application to separately install the Open XML SDK.